# Using ValueConverter to filter routes in Aurelia - routes are always empty

Tags: aurelia

In nav-bar.html I have

```
<li repeat.for="row of router.navigation | routeLanguageFilter2" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
```

The I thought it would be fairly straight-forward to setup a filter for the routes doing:

```
export class RouteLanguageFilter2ValueConverter {
    toView(routes) {
        console.log(routes);
        let self = this;

        let res = [];
        for (let r of routes) {
            res.push(r);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

However routes is always [] when I console.log them out:/ What am i doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

Changed the title and quite a lot of the original question, since it turned out I was a bit confused and not focussing on the main problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dnCtpI?p=preview

I figured out the problem, however I'm pretty lost how to find another way to achieve the same goal. Inside my nav-bar.html I had it like this:

```
<div if.bind="true"> <!-- could be anything -->
            <require from="../styles/blah.css"></require>
            <div class="container" id="banner">
                <img src="images/logo.png" />
            </div>
            <require from="nav-bar"></require>
            <nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>
        <div class="page-host">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I removed the `<div if.bind="xxx">` part, it worked. However now I just have that other problem which I dont know how to solve in other ways :-)

Anyways thanks fops, but my plunkr didn't really illustrate my real problem. I made it a bit too fast it seems. :/

Answer (score 0):

[working example:](http://plnkr.co/edit/t4qN9Zo7ppeSWr8so3Db?p=preview)

well short summary:
there was a missing parenthese and its best practise to use a settings object on the route if adding extra params (your languageId)

```
 { route: ['','welcome'],  moduleId: './welcome',      nav: true, title:'Welcome', settings: {languageId:13} },
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing if.bind with show.bind did the trick.